# WSDL for uuid generator

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I need to use a web service in my project. Where I use a WSDL of a uuid generator web service. I tried looking for a web service that does this but couldn't find anything.
I can't make my own java program for that because my requirement is i have to use an available free web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using:

https://httpbin.org/uuid

It's not SOAP, but REST, however this should actually be easier to use.

e.g.

```
curl https://httpbin.org/uuid
```